# SVN remove changes from repository, but keep them in my checkout?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a few files that were part of an update that were mistakenly committed to the main trunk before they were ready. Is there a way to 'undo' this checkout and roll the repository back a version, while still keeping the changed file in my checkout?

I'm using tortiseSVN ver 1.6.5 on Windows XP, if that makes any difference.

example: I updated a file, it is now at revision 659, previous version of this file was 600. I would like to keep version 659 on my checkout, but make what is currently version 600 the latest one again (ie version 660).

I tried making a copy of my current version, rolled back the regular version to 600, then tried to commit it back, but it tells me there are no changes to commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually copy the file I want to keep to a temporary location, do the rollback, then copy the preserved file back in...  Though, for all I know, I'm just taking the easy approach and there's something better out there.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo), not an update to an old revision.

Let's say the revision you just committed (and want to roll back) was 42.

```
# rollback
svn merge -c -42
svn commit
# now r43 is good but we want r42's version of foo.c in our working copy
svn merge -c -43 foo.c
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you’d use “Update to revision” which will revert your working copy to a specified revision number after which you can commit back. For the sake of simplicity, I’d do this *after* taking a copy of your current working directory then just move the copy back after the update.

Comment: This will not work; you can't commit after an update to an old revision.  You have to do a reverse merge, otherwise SVN will say there are no changes to commit.  Updating to an old revision doesn't count as a change.

Comment: You're right Michael, brain fade on my part. Full details on doing this with Tortoise here: http://www.coderenaissance.com/2008/11/how-to-revert-or-rollback-file-using.html